# AWS Lambda doesn't have DynamoDB permissions when invoked by URL/API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

We have a pair of existing AWS Lambda functions that read/write from a DynamoDB table. I created a new function and table; the function is very basic, just does a putItem on the DynamoDB table. I can successfully invoke it with the test functionality in Lambda.
However, if I invoke the Lambda function using the FunctionURL or via API Gateway, I get the following error.
[image: Logs]

Yet in Configuration > Permissions in the Lambda interface I clearly see the permission:
[image: Lambda Config]

Suggestions where to check next? Comparison to our existing, working functions hasn't revealed anything; everything I have checked in configured the same.

Thanks!

Comment: Your lambda function is being invoked with an IAM role which doesn't have the required permission

Comment: Paolo, is this distinct from the "Execution Role" shown in the Configuration > Permissions tab of the Lambda Functions UI? That role does have a permission policy attached with an DynamoDB:PutItem action and the relevant table as a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke the lambda function in the lambda console, lambda is using an *Execution role*.

When you invoke the lambda function via API gateway or via the function URL, it is likely that you are using `IAM` authorization. As a result, lambda is using *the role of the principal* who invoked the function (in this case, `PatientWellnessDeregistration-role-3ospc0u3`).

The execution role is configured correctly, but the IAM role of the principal is lacking the required permissions.

Further reading:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-auth.html

Answer (score -1):

What you could optionally check is that API Gateway is authorized to call your new Lambda. If so, then the **Resource-based policy** of the Lambda (still in the **Permissions** tab) should have something similar to:

Resource-based policy example:

[image: Resource-based policy example]

Comment: Yes, I've got that. One for API Gateway and another for the Function URL.